# Python + QT: How to make non-GUI Blocking loading screen?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

New to PySide, so might have mistaken fundamentals here.

I'm writing a GUI app that will start, and then do various system checks:

- Check for HW presence
- Check for net connectivity
- Check for API connectivity

Throughout the process, it will be informing the user of what it's currently doing, and the result.

When it's done the checks (and passed) - they'll get taken to the program initial screen.

Currently, I'd been attempting to run the checks, with `QApplication.processEvents` in a timer:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    rebadger = rebadger()
    rebadger.initUI()
    rebadger.show()

    tT = QTimer()
    tT.setSingleShot(False)
    tT.timeout.connect(QApplication.processEvents)
    tT.start(1000)

    rebadger.rebadgeObj.runChecks()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But everything still blocks until the checks have done.

I've gone over the `QThread` documentation, but I'm finding it rather difficult to wrap my head around the event logic (having come from a strict PHP background)

Any assistance in sketching out a skeleton of how to acheive this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how you could do what you want, check the use of `QThread`s for long running background processing, as an extra you will have a responsive gui so it works for any window not just a splash screen:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore as core, QtGui as gui
import time

class MyProccess(core.QThread):

    newProgress = core.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self,i):
        super(MyProccess,self).__init__()
        self.id = i

    def run(self):
        for j in range(10):
            self.newProgress.emit('task %d at %d%%' % (self.id,j*10))
            time.sleep(0.2)            


class MySplash(gui.QSplashScreen):

    def __init__(self,mw):
        super(MySplash,self).__init__()
        layout = gui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.text = gui.QLabel(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.text) 
        self.setGeometry(300,300,100,0)          

        self.task1 = MyProccess(1)
        self.task2 = MyProccess(2)
        self.task3 = MyProccess(3)

        self.task1.newProgress.connect(self.showProgress)
        self.task2.newProgress.connect(self.showProgress)
        self.task3.newProgress.connect(self.showProgress)

        self.task1.finished.connect(self.task2.start)
        self.task2.finished.connect(self.task3.start)
        self.task3.finished.connect(mw.show)
        self.task3.finished.connect(self.hide)

    @core.pyqtSlot(str)
    def showProgress(self,msg):
        self.text.setText(msg)

    def event(self,ev):
        if type(ev) == gui.QShowEvent:
            self.task1.start()
        return super(MySplash,self).event(ev)

app = gui.QApplication([])

mw = gui.QMainWindow()

cw = gui.QWidget()
l = gui.QHBoxLayout()
cw.setLayout(l)
welcome = gui.QLabel()
welcome.setText('Welcome back!')
l.addWidget(welcome)

mw.setCentralWidget(cw)
mw.setGeometry(200,200,300,300)


w = MySplash(mw)
w.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: This is perfect: progress is posted back from the threads, threads are progressive / ordered, GUI isn't blocked, and life can continue afterwards. Can you explain the **@core.pyqtSlot(str)** reference slightly please?

Comment: `MyProcess` holds an unused reference to the label (`self.out`) which could tempt to use its setText() method from within the thread. As far as I know this should not be done and so there is no sense in that variable.

Comment: @TNT yes you are right, but I don use it, maybe it remains from an earlier version of my answer, I didn't realize it till now ;) thanks

Comment: @swx The decorator `@core.pyqtSlot` is used to mark a method as a slot in PyQt (in my code is not strictly necessary but it's a good programming practice) you should read [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator) if you wan to learn how/why to use, hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe `QSplashScreen` is what you need:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                       

    import time                                                                                  
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)                                                           
    splash = QtGui.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap('splash.png'))                                    
    splash.show()                                                                                
    for n in ("HW presence", "net connectivity", "API connectivity"):                            
        splash.showMessage("Check for {0}".format(n))                                            
        time.sleep(1)                                                                            
        app.processEvents()                                                                      
    mainWin = MainWindow()                                                                       
    splash.finish(mainWin)                                                                       
    mainWin.show()                                                                               
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi TNT - thanks for your reply. I'd used / attempted to use SplashScreen, but had found it not adapted to what I was wanting (IE, design restricted to a simple image that, closure upon being clicked, and certainly that didn't _solve_ the problem by still needing processEvents() to be called. In theory, if it should for splashScreen, it would work for any other regular form as well ?

Comment: Indeed, for example with the `mainWin` where you could use a statusbar for your output. But also needing `processEvents()`.

Comment: But if the tasks in the for loop take a lengthy period to process, the GUI still blocks..